# Developing a custom theme in Wordpress (NOT a child theme) and my style.css does not load for a subpage with template

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

So, I have developed many Wordpress sites and this has never happened to me before, I have been fighting with this for hours and can't find a solution, so here I turn to you guys.

I am developing a site on WP, with my own custom theme coded from scratch right, there is no other themes present in my /themes directory.

I am using Less and Webpack, all production dependencies are required in the main.js file in /src directory:

**/src/main.js**

```
// main.js

// Webpack
require('./bootstrap.min');
require('../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
require('../css/bootstrap.min.css');
require('../css/all.css');
require('./all');
require('../style.less');
```

and everything is bundled in /dist/bundle.js that I load in functions.php (classic practice ofc):

**functions.php**

```
<?php
/* functions.php */
?>
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bundle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/bundle.js', array('jquery'), 1, false );
}
?>
<?php
/**
 * Fix Template Caching - Bug Fix for Wordpress 4.9+
 * Plugin name: WP Trac #42573: Fix for theme template file caching.
 * Description: Flush the theme file cache each time the admin screens are loaded which uses the file list.
 * Plugin URI: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42573
 * Author: Weston Ruter, XWP.
 * Author URI: https://weston.ruter.net
 */
function wp_42573_fix_template_caching( WP_Screen $current_screen ) {
    // Only flush the file cache with each request to post list table, edit post screen, or theme editor.
    if ( ! in_array( $current_screen->base, array( 'post', 'edit', 'theme-editor' ), true ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    if ( ! $theme ) {
        return;
    }
    $cache_hash = md5( $theme->get_theme_root() . '/' . $theme->get_stylesheet() );
    $label = sanitize_key( 'files_' . $cache_hash . '-' . $theme->get( 'Version' ) );
    $transient_key = substr( $label, 0, 29 ) . md5( $label );
    delete_transient( $transient_key );
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'wp_42573_fix_template_caching' );
?>
```

Now, when I go to **front-page.php** my index page, the CSS loads just fine, everything is okay.

Problem started when I created a Page in wp-admin and a template for it, suddenly the subpage shows up without any CSS applied.

! I did try to flush cache

! Less compiles to CSS without any error

! Webpack bundles everything without error

! I do have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in my header

! What is even more surprising, when I inspect the subpage, it shows my CSS properly loaded in the  and it is last, so definitely not overwritten by other stylesheet.
! I have no idea wtf is happening.

Please let me know, what other files you may need to see, I can add later.

Thank you very much.

Wordpress version is 5.3 btw.

**UPDATE**

So I have tried additionally enqueuing the stylesheet on top of the bundle like this:

```
<?php
function enqueue_my_custom_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_styles', 15);
?>
```

and it has made **couple of changes** meaning couple of CSS rules got applied but only like 1%, this must mean my CSS is linked properly but is being overwritten by something. Also the JS code in the bundle run properly.

I have noticed I wierd thing in my webpack bundle though, I will link image below (Wierd part highlighted in orange). It seems as if those files are getting bundled twice.

Oh and btw, I did exclude node_modules, both for each loader, and also with

```
 target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
```

This really seems to be a tough one.

[image: Wierd part highlighted in orange]

Comment: Have you tried enqueueing your compiled css file separately, instead of just the js file - to see if it loads from that?

Comment: Well I just tried.. absolutely shocking to see, it has made few changes (applied style to a random span class I have there) but rest stayed the same unstyled... so I guess this proofs, my CSS is linked but is being overwritten by other stylesheet.. also the relevant JS code from the bundle does work.